# Angular Directive not working within table element

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a directive that for some reason isnt rendering! The controller is working fine, and other angular parts are loading within that module, so I havent broken angular as such. Simply the directive isnt being rendered.
[Please see the plunkr here](http://plnkr.co/edit/Zv3PTMdHpUROSc4nksgC?p=preview)
or read below:
my directive is:

```
    departmentModule.directive('AssignmentRow', function () {
        return {
            templateUrl: '_row.html'
        };
    });
```

_row.html simply contains the word "hi".

In my index.html page is this (simplified for brevity):

```
<table>
    <tr ng-repeat="c in d.children">
        <td assignment-row></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Sorry -im a noob, and im postive its extremely simple - but i cant figure out whats wrong!
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi - just an update - its something to do with the name of the directive. I changed it simply to 'row' and it renders! But would still like to know what i did wrong if anyone is willing to check the naming on my directive. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This is because **AngularJS** will handle translating the camel cased name when we define **directive** to the snake case when we invoke it.

the problem is the directive name not in camel cased name

```
 departmentModule.directive('assignmentRow', function () {
    return {
        templateUrl: '_row.html'
    };
});
```

in HTML

```
<table>
    <tr ng-repeat="c in d.children">
        <td assignment-row></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

if name directive **ngSpark** , directive reference is **ng-spark**, this is the solution for the problem currently facing.

Comment: Thank you - clearly explained. Had no idea that first capital letter was killing it!